# A non well formed numeric value encountered - Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have an application which has Purchase Return feature. I am not able to add more than 3 items in the purchase return. Going to the log it says,

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

This happens in line number 96 which has the following code

```
$input_data['transaction_date'] = $this->productUtil->uf_date($input_data['transaction_date'], true);
$input_data['total_before_tax'] = $input_data['final_total'] - $input_data['tax_amount'];
```

Looks like there is some numeric / string conversion issue. Couldnt figure out. Any suggestions.

Comment: what data type does method `->uf_date()` accept in the first arg? I think it accepts an integer. maybe try `strtotime(  $input_data['transaction_date'] )`

Comment: It is an integer, tried this `strtotime(  $input_data['transaction_date'] )` and this doesn't seem to work.